# Problema con formato de numero, suma en jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo 3 campos que se toman de un formulario, y necesito darle formato automático con . como separador de mil (formato de numero en Colombia) y que estos campos se sumen y muestre el resultado en un cuarto campo.

Pero me convierte los números en decimales al sumarlos y al respuesta me da incorrecta.

Campo 1 ingreso: 1111 y se formatea a 1.111
Campo 2 ingreso: 2222 y se formatea a 2.222
Campo 3 ingreso: 3333 y se formatea a 3.333  hasta ahí todo bien, pero al ejecutar la suma me muestra en el campo de resultado: 3.336.333

Este el el código:

```js
//suma ingresos
$('.Ingresos').keyup(function() {
  var ingreso_total = 0
    $(".Ingresos").each(
      function(index, value) {
          if ( $.isNumeric( $(this).val() ) ){
            ingreso_total  = ingreso_total + eval($(this).val());
          }
    }
  );
      $("#TotalIngresos").val(ingreso_total);
});

//Formatea numeros
$(":text").on({
  "focus": function(event) {
    $(event.target).select();
  },
  "keyup": function(event) {
    $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control Ingresos" id="Salario" placeholder="123.456">
<input type="text" class="form-control Ingresos" id="SalarioConyuge" placeholder="123.456">
<input type="text" class="form-control Ingresos" id="OtrosIngresos" placeholder="123.456">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="TotalIngresos" placeholder="123.456">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//suma ingresos
function sumarIngresos() {
      var ingreso_total = 0
        $(".Ingresos").each(
          function(index, value) {
              if ( $.isNumeric( $(this).val() ) ){
                ingreso_total += parseFloat($(this).val());
              }
        }
      );
          $("#TotalIngresos").val(ingreso_total);
}

//Formatea numeros
$(":text").on({
  "focus": function(event) {
    $(event.target).select();
  },
  "keyup": function(event) {
    $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
    });

    sumarIngresos();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control Ingresos" id="Salario" placeholder="123.456">
<input type="text" class="form-control Ingresos" id="SalarioConyuge" placeholder="123.456">
<input type="text" class="form-control Ingresos" id="OtrosIngresos" placeholder="123.456">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="TotalIngresos" placeholder="123.456">
```

Tu problema era que se estaba ejecutando el evento `keyup` antes de formatear los numeros, en consecuencia te sumaba cantidades indeseadas, la solución a esto es llamar a la función `sumarIngresos` despues de que se hayan tratado los numeros:

```
//Formatea numeros
$(":text").on({
  "focus": function(event) {
    $(event.target).select();
  },
  "keyup": function(event) {
    $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
    });

    //Aquí
    sumarIngresos();
  }
});
```

Comment: Tambien se te había olvidado algo muy importante, los input tipo texto siempre devuelven strings en su value, cuando hayas tratados los datos debes convertir siempre el numero como texto a un float, de lo contrario veras cosas extrañas.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @McGus007 recuerda que si mi respuesta fue de ayuda o respondio a tu pregunta, puedes darle al boton que parece un chulo para dar la respuesta como aceptada.